# Name for extension of the symplectic group

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, terminology, notation

Let $S_g$ denote an ortientable surface of genus $g$. Let $\operatorname{Diff}(S_g)$ denote the group of diffeomorphism (that need not fix the orientation). Is there a name for the image of $\operatorname{Diff}(S_g) \to \operatorname{Aut}(H_1(S_g))=GL_{2n}(\mathbb Z)$? It is called symplectic group if we restrict to diffeomorphisms that preserve the orientation.

Comment: Do you really need a special name? You can just say that *your favourite letter* is a group preserving symplectic form up to sign and use that letter as a name. Signed symplectic group is one of you really need one.

Comment: I think it is sometimes written $GSp_{2g}(\mathbb{Z})$, and called the group of symplectic similitudes.

Comment: @OscarRandal-Williams, since [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432928/name-for-extension-of-the-symplectic-group#comment1114547_432928) seems (by my understanding and by voting!) clearly to be the right answer, maybe you could post it as such so that it can be accepted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it is sometimes written $\operatorname{GSp}_{2g}(\mathbb{Z})$, and called the group of symplectic similitudes